# Chi-squared test in a meta-analysis for >2 samples in R

Tags: r, chi-squared, heterogeneous

I'm trying to perform a chi-squared test for my [data](https://files.fm/u/z2dzf4ek) to test for heterogeneity. The data records the incubation period time for 10 studies. I'm really struggling because of the missing values and 0's. Is it even possible to test for homogeneity with a data set like this? I've tried to use `chisq.test` but I keep getting this error:

```
df <- read_excel("df.xlsx")
chisq.test(df)
Error in chisq.test(df) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

    Study   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
    s1      4   6   2   3   1   5   4   0   0   1           
    s2      3   0   0   20  15  20  12                      
    s3      0   2   2   0   1                               
    s4      0   7   15  4   6   8   5   6   8   0   0   1   5
    s5                                                  
    s6                                                  
    s7                                                  
    s8      2   10  20  18  16  6   4   3   0   3           
    s9      0   9   6   5   2   2                           
    s10
```

Comment: Please can you include a sample of your data in the question?

Comment: Done. It includes missing rows and missing values

Comment: I suspect that it is your missing rows that are causing the issue.

Comment: Even if I remove them with `df <- df[!apply(is.na(df[, -1]), 1, all),]` I still get the error